# What is the difference between should and boost final score calculation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a little confused about what is the difference between `should` and `boost` final score calculation

- when a bool query has a `must` clause, the `should` clauses act as a boost factor, meaning none of them have to match but if they do, the relevancy **score for that document will be boosted** and thus appear higher in the result.
- so,if we have:

one query which contains `must` and `should` clauses

vs

second query which contains `must` clause and `boosting` clause

1. Is there a difference ?
2. when you recommend to use `must` and `should` vs `must` and `boosting` clauses in a query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the documentation of boolean query [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), there is huge difference in the `should` and `boost`.

`Should` and `must` both contributes to the `_score` of the document, and as mentioned in the above documentation, follows the

> The bool query takes a more-matches-is-better approach, so the score from each matching must or should clause will be added together to provide the final _score for each document.

While `boost` is a parameter, using which you can increase the `weight` according to your value, let me explain that using an example.

**Index sample docs**

```
POST _doc/1
{
  "brand" : "samsung",
  "name" : "samsung phone"
}

POST _doc/2

{
  "brand" : "apple",
  "name" : "apple phone"
}
```

Boolean Query using `should` without `boost`

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": {
                            "query": "apple"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "brand": {
                            "query": "apple"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result showing score**

```
"max_score": 1.3862942,
```

**Now in same query use `boost` of factor 10**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": {
                            "query": "apple"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "brand": {
                            "query": "apple",
                            "boost": 10 --> Note additional boost
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Query result showing boost**

```
"max_score": 7.624619, (Note considerable high score)
```

**In short, when you want to boost a particular document containing your query term, you can additionally pass the `boost` param and it will be on top of the normal score calculated by `should` or `must`.**